# Schema.org sameAs does not show all social media links?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a website which has the following sameAs JSON-Ld property:

```
sameAs": ["https://www.facebook.com/AZFitnessEquipment","https://www.instagram.com/azfitnessequip","https://twitter.com/AZFitnessEquip"]
```

You can view the whole markup here:

```
view-source:https://azfitnessequipment.com/
```

However, Google shows only the Instagram page in the Navigation pane of the search results. You can see it here:

https://www.google.bg/search?q=az+fitness+equipment+ltd

Why is Google not showing the Facebook and Twitter links?

Comment: FWIW, it doesn’t show any profile links for me. -- From [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-site#add-your-sites-name-logo-and-social-links): "Google algorithms process the social profiles you specify and then display the most relevant ones in response to users' queries."

Comment: I examined your markup and double-checked the Google docs. Seems everything fine to me. Read [this](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/social-profiles-missing-from-googles-knowledge-graph/) instructions. Did you check, if the "your social media profiles are verified"? That's also mentioned in the Google docs (see comment above). Good luck!